# How do I use an array of character arrays defined in the class def in the class body in C++?

Tags: c++

How do I use an array of character arrays when my setup looks like this:

In classes.h

```
    namespace foomaker
    {
        class foo
        {
            const char  **mystringarray;

            bool ipitythefoo ();

        };
    }
```

In foo.cpp
        #include classes.h

```
    namespace foomaker
    {

        bool foo::ipitythefoo()
        {
            *mystringarray[] = {"Mr. T","Gold Chains","Mohawks"};

            return false;
        };
    }
```

Compiler is throwing errors:

```
    1>.\foofactory.cpp(5) : error C2059: syntax error : ']'
    1>.\foofactory.cpp(5) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
    1>.\foofactory.cpp(5) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
```

Or is this even possible?

Unable to use strings, maps, or vectors for this.

The end-result is that this will be for error strings that I need to get by position number. The error strings are specific to this class.

Thanks

Comment: Functions don't have semicolons after them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is not possible. You are trying to re-initialize an array, and that cannot be done. Perhaps, given that your use case is for error strings, you can do something like this:

```
    bool foo::ipitythefoo()
    {
        static const char* actualstringarray[] = {"Mr. T","Gold Chains","Mohawks"};
        *mystringarray = actualstringarray;

        return false;
    };
```

But then, it'd make more sense for an array of error strings to be `static` to begin with.